# easyUI two datagrids on one site, second toolbar not shown in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I have two easyUI datagrids on one site in different tabs. The toolbar of the first datagrid is visible in IE 8. The toolbar of the second grid is not shown and i receive a javascript error.
Message: `'colspan' is null or not an object. on line 8986 in jquery.easyui.min.js`
This error is only at IE 8. In firefox it is working well. But i need it in IE 8.
What can i do?

Griddefinition:

```
//Datagrid 1
$('#datagridcostrates').datagrid({
    fitColumns:true,
    idField:"idnr",
    remoteSort:false,
    sortName:"startDate",
    sortOrder:"desc",
    singleSelect:true,
    view:scrollview,
    striped:true,
    url:'getCarrierCostrates.php',
    method:'get',
    toolbar:'#datagridcostratesToolbar',
    columns:[[
        {field:'setupFee',title:'<span title="one time charge">OTC</span>',width:65},
        {field:'monthlyFee',title:'<span title="monthly recurring charge">MRC</span>',width:65},
        {field:'Rateperminute',title:'<span title="cost per minute">CPM</span>',width:65},
        {field:'portationFee',title:'portation fee',width:80},
        {field:'startDate',title:'startdate',width:70,sortable:true},
        {field:'idnr',title:'id',hidden:true}
    ]]
});


//Datagrid 2
$('#datagridsellrates').datagrid({
    fitColumns:true,
    idField:"idnr",
    remoteSort:true,
    sortName:"startDate",
    sortOrder:"desc",
    singleSelect:true,
    view:scrollview,
    striped:true,
    autoRowHeight:true,
    url:'getCarrierSellrates.php',
    method:'get',
    toolbar:'#datagridsellratesToolbar',
    columns:[[
        {field:'otcUSD',title:'<span title="one time charge in US dollar">OTC $</span>',width:55},
        {field:'otcEUR',title:'<span title="one time charge in euro">OTC €</span>',width:55},
        {field:'mrcUSD',title:'<span title="monthly recurring charge in US dollar">MRC $</span>',width:55},
        {field:'mrcEUR',title:'<span title="monthly recurring charge in euro">MRC €</span>',width:55},
        {field:'portationUSD',title:'<span title="portation fee in US dollar">portation $</span>',width:80},
        {field:'portationEUR',title:'<span title="portation fee in euro">portation €</span>',width:80},
        {field:'rpm',title:'<span title="cost per minute in euro. Other currencies are calculatet depending on exchangerates.">RPM €</span>',width:55},
        {field:'startDateSell',title:'startdate',width:70,sortable:true},
        {field:'idnr',title:'id',hidden:true},
    ]]
});
```

HTML-code:

```
<!--**********Cost*************-->
<div id="tabs-5" title="Cost" style="height:300px; padding:10px;">
    <table id="datagridcostrates" class="easyui-datagrid"  style="width:600px; height:100%;" >
    </table>
    <div id="datagridcostratesToolbar" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onClick="newrate('cost')">New</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onClick="editrate('cost')">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onClick="removerate('cost')">Remove</a>
    </div>

</div>
<!--**********Sell*************-->
<div id="tabs-6" title="Sell" style="height:300px; padding:10px;">
    <table id="datagridsellrates" class="easyui-datagrid"  style="width:600px; height:100%;" >
    </table>
    <div id="datagridsellratesToolbar" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onClick="newrate('sell')">New</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onClick="editrate('sell')">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onClick="removerate('sell')">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, the toolbar **is** shown. But not on the top of the grid. It is shown somewhere on the site.
But i can still see no data. All data is visible in the JSON file but not shown in the grid an i still reveive the javascript error.
I have installed the new easyUI to get all bugfixes.